# Attribute error when using user object on tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to write a program that will stream tweets from Twitter using their Stream API and Tweepy. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    if data.user.id == "25073877" or data.in_reply_to_user_id == "25073877":
        self.filename = trump.csv

    elif data.user.id == "30354991" or data.in_reply_to_user_id == "30354991":
        self.filename = harris.csv

    if not 'RT @' in data.text:
        csvFile = open(self.filename, 'a')
        csvWriter = csv.write(csvFile)

        print(data.text)
        try:
            csvWriter.writerow([data.text, data.created_at, data.user.id, data.user.screen_name,  data.in_reply_to_status_id])

        except:
            pass

def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
        return False
```

What the code should be doing is streaming the tweets and writing the text of the tweet, the creation date, the user ID of the tweeter, their screen name, and the reply ID of the status they're replying to if the tweet is a reply. However, I get the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 13, in on_data

 if data.user.id == "25073877" or data.in_reply_to_user_id == "25073877":

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

EDIT: Sample of what is being read into "data"

```
{"created_at":"Fri Feb 15 20:50:46 +0000 2019","id":1096512164347760651,"id_str":"1096512164347760651","text":"@realDonaldTrump \nhttps:\/\/t.co\/NPwSuJ6V2M","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":25073877,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"25073877","in_reply_to_screen_name":"realDonaldTrump","user":{"id":1050189031743598592,"id_str":"1050189031743598592","name":"Lauren","screen_name":"switcherooskido","location":"United States","url":null,"description":"Concerned citizen of the USA who would like to see Integrity restored in the US Government. Anti-marxist!\nSigma, INTP\/J\nREJECT PC and Identity Politics #WWG1WGA","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1459,"friends_count":1906,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":5311,"statuses_count":8946,"created_at":"Thu Oct 11 00:59:11 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"FF691F","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1068591478329495558\/ng_tNAXx_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1068591478329495558\/ng_tNAXx_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1050189031743598592\/1541441602","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/NPwSuJ6V2M","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.conservativereview.com\/news\/5-insane-provisions-amnesty-omnibus-bill\/","display_url":"conservativereview.com\/news\/5-insane-\u2026","indices":[18,41]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"realDonaldTrump","name":"Donald J. Trump","id":25073877,"id_str":"25073877","indices":[0,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"und","timestamp_ms":"1550263846848"}
```

So I supposed the revised question is how to tell the program to only write parts of this JSON output to the CSV file? I've been using the references Twitter's stream API provides for the attributes for "data".

Comment: You need to post more of your code. The error is telling you that the `data` variable you are passing to your `on_data` function is a `unicode` object, probably not what you are expecting it to be. It therefore does not have a `user` attribute. Try printing `data` to find out what you are actually passing

Comment: @liamhawkins the output is the tweet data in JSON format. I can't post an entire thing here due to the character limit, but I edited the post to include a sample output. Also that's the entire body of my code, not including the package declarations, the indentification keys for Twitter's API, and the class declaration

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comment the tweet data is in "JSON format". I believe what you mean by this is that it is a string (unicode) in JSON format, not a parsed JSON object. In order to access the fields like you want to in your code you need to parse the data string using `json`.

e.g.

```
import json

json_data_object = json.loads(data)
```

you can then access the fields like you would a dictionary e.g.

```
json_data_object['some_key']['some_other_key']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but I'm answering here because this is the first search hit when you search for this error. I was also using Tweepy and found that the JSON response object had attributes that could not be accessed.

```
'Response' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Through lots of tinkering and research, I found that in the loop where you access the Twitter API, using Tweepy, you must specify '.data' in the loop, not within it.
For example:

```
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query = "covid" , tweet.fields = ['text'])
for tweet in tweets:
  print(tweet.text) # or print(tweet.data.text)
```

Will not work because the Response variable doesn't have access to the attributes within the JSON response object. Instead, you do something like:

```
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query = "covid" , tweet.fields = ['text'])
for tweet in tweets.data:
  print(tweet.text)
```

Basically, this was a long-winded way to fix a problem I was having for a long time. Cheers, hopefully, other noobs like me won't have to struggle as long as I did!